# Prevent LaTeX beamer from writing on top of frame

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I created a template for LaTeX beamer that has a background picture so that it looks like there was a heading, the rest is white. Now I don't want to have any content on the top (let's say) 10 percent of the frame. Somehow an invisible header. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why I am new, I'm active in Stackoverflow for a while.

Comment: I guess they determine "newness" for each site separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick workaround:

Invent an invisible headline of a height of your choice

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\rule{0pt}{3cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```